# Migrating from Migrate to Spring MVC 4 + Hibernate5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gradle, spring-boot

I'm migrating an application from Jersey 1.18, Spring 3, Hibernate 3.6, Maven to a completely new architecture: **Spring 4.3** (via Spring Boot), **Hibernate 5** and **Gradle**.

During the "porting" of the Spring **application.xml** to a Code-Base configuration, I'm facing the following exception:

**Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Unsatisfied dependency** ... **No qualifying bean found for dependency [java.util.Set]**

Here the long stacktrace

```
2017-03-13 19:44:42.814  WARN 40010 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2017-03-13 19:44:42.816  INFO 40010 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-03-13 19:44:42.825  INFO 40010 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-03-13 19:44:42.860  INFO 40010 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-03-13 19:44:42.995 ERROR 40010 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.DefaultJpaContext required a bean of type 'java.util.Set' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.util.Set' in your configuration.
```

**The fact is that I didn't define the DefaultJpaContext in my code:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired private Environment env;
    @Autowired private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static final String DB_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_DIALECT    = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_VALIDATION = "validate";
    private static final String SHOW_SQL             = "false";
    private static final String ENTITY_PACKAGE       = MainEntity.class.getPackage().getName();

    final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfig.class);


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final String driverName = env.getProperty("db.driver", DB_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);
        final String url        = env.getProperty("db.url");
        final String username   = env.getProperty("db.username");
        final String password   = env.getProperty("db.password");
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            log.info("Database Configuration:");
            log.info("Setting driverName to {}", driverName);
            log.info("Setting url to {}", url);
            log.info("Setting username to {}", username);
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) log.warn("Password not specified");
            else log.info("Setting password");
        }

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {ENTITY_PACKAGE});

        // Hibernate properties
        Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.dialect"     , env.getProperty("db.dialect"   , HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("db.validation", HIBERNATE_VALIDATION));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql"    , env.getProperty("db.sql.show"  , SHOW_SQL));

        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(additionalProperties);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**Update**

Here it is a piece of gradle build:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
// ...
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile group: 'org.hibernate'        , name: 'hibernate-core'     , version: '5.2.8.Final'
// ...
```

What I'm missing?

Thanks, Davide.

Comment: `DefaultJpaContext` is defined in auto-configuration. Run with debug enabled as suggested in error report to see details. But what you are doing is not necessary.  All the properties can be defined in `application.properties` and spring-boot will pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the spring boot error message, it fails to build the `DefaultJpaContext` bean whose constructor requires `Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager> entityManagers`.

Looks like you have `Spring-Data` dependency in your `pom.xml`(or `build.gradle`) which requires the jpa `EntityManagerFactory` while you have Hibernate(`LocalSessionFactoryBean`) stuff.  Do you have to have `DefaultJpaContext` bean?

Comment: Yes, I have spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency, but without I have no @Transactional annotation available. I don't really need entity manager, because I use SessionFactory in this project.

Comment: IF your problem is just with `@ Transactional` annotation, then just add `spring-tx` as your dependency. The point here is try to minimize the dependency you declare. That is one of the few *drawbacks* with `Spring-boot` where we just blindly declare a bunch of `starters` which sometime introduce a lot of dependencies we do not actually need. Like here in your case, you do not need JPA but just hibernate related jars, then you do not need to touch those jpa starters.